# Online reinforcement learning on cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, reinforcement-learning

My question is:

**Can we implement an online reinforcement learning on the cloud?**

I mean by receiving real-time data from the firebase (for example), can the model be retrained and updated?

It is a Deep Q-learning model using tensorflow.
Based on my searches, I just found about running online RL over Raspberry Pi or similar devices.

Comment: Why do you think it could be a problem receiving real-time data from Firebase?

Comment: Let me explain it at this way: I am looking for a way to have an online RL model on the cloud (GCP), We would like to train an online deep Q-learning agent on the cloud platform.
How can we train an online RL model by receiving rewards and first state on firebase real-time database? (next states are recognized based on the maximum Q_values for actions but the rewards still come from the Firebase Real-Time DataBase)
Regarding that after each data ingestion, the model should be updated with new weights, where this model is going to be kept on the cloud for the next updates and improvements?

Comment: Well, maybe I haven't understood all the requirement, but a first glance I don't see any problem to implement what you are describing. While the agent be able to receive the states and rewards, everything should work fine. Or are you asking about real time performance?